# When building a website, how to combine multiple small images into a big one?

Tags: javascript, image, web, web-performance

[image: Image downloaded from google front page]

Hi, when I open google front page in chrome developer tool, I found that they have bundled multiple icons into a large png file and then download them together(as above). I think this is a somewhat common approach to accelerate page loading. Can someone point to me a how to do that? Better yet is there a library to handle the bundle/debundle?

(I spent quite some time online searching for this but can't find exactly what I need. Any help would be appreciated!)

Comment: The term you need to search for is "CSS sprites"

Comment: EG. https://css-tricks.com/css-sprites/

Comment: @Paulpro Thanks you! It's very helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here you have a [jsfiddle](https://fiddle.jshell.net/anushach/qtkcaa6h/) .
This code below is for one icon. You can move your big image around with `background-position`

```
.sprite-gmail {
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    background-position: -45px -5px;
}
```

Here you have a good [post](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_image_sprites.asp) from w3Schools to better understand how to get what you want

Comment: Thank you it's very helpful!

Comment: Good to hear that :)